# How to compute the laps covered by a car in python

Tags: python

Edited:I have a scene, whose size is height=6 and width=6. I need to compute the lap covered by the car, so my logic is to compute the centre point which is (3,3), and pass a horizontal line from that centre, now I pass car coordinates to check if the car has passed through horizontal line  and reaches the starting point then make it a one lap. I am attaching the below code. It is giving me count 2 which is correct but sometimes it gives me wring answer. what i am doing wrong.

```
def count_laps(df, width, height, starting_y, tolerance_y=0.01):
    """
    Count the number of laps completed by a car based on its coordinates, without assuming a specific direction.
    
    Args:
        df (DataFrame): DataFrame containing the car's coordinates with columns 'XCoordinate' and 'YCoordinate'.
        width (float): Width of the track.
        height (float): Height of the track.
        starting_x (float): X-coordinate of the starting point.
        tolerance_x (float): Tolerance value for starting point's X-coordinate. Default is 0.01.
    
    Returns:
        int: Number of laps completed by the car.
    """
    center_x = width / 2
    center_y = height / 2
    lap_count = 0
    crossed_ref = False
    prev_y = None
    for coord in df:
        x = coord[0]
        y = coord[1]
    
        # Check if the car has crossed the reference position
        if not crossed_ref and prev_y is not None and ((y > (starting_y - tolerance_y) and prev_y <= center_y and y > center_y) or
                                                      (y < (starting_y + tolerance_y) and prev_y >= center_y and y < center_y)):
            crossed_ref = True

        # Check if the car has crossed the horizontal line and completed a lap
        if crossed_ref and prev_y is not None and ((y <= (starting_y + tolerance_y) and y > center_y and prev_y <= center_y) or
                                                   (y >= (starting_y - tolerance_y) and y < center_y and prev_y >= center_y)):
            crossed_ref = False
            lap_count += 1
        prev_y = y
    
    return lap_count
# Example list of coordinates
result = [(4, 2), (2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 2), (4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 2.01),(2, 2), (2, 3), (4, 3), (4, 2.01)]
# Example list of coordinates
#coordinates = [(4, 2), (2, 3), (4, 3), (2, 2), (4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 2), (2, 1), (1, 1), (2, 2), (4, 1), (2, 1), (4, 2)]


starting_x = 4
starting_y = 2.01
width = 6
height = 6
lap_count = count_laps(result, width, height, starting_y, tolerance_y=0.01)
print("Lap Count: ", lap_count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`returned_to_start` will never be set to True to increment the lap because `starting_x` is 3 and none of your test points are within the 0.5 tolerance value you've set (they are all either 2 or 4). `crossed_right_to_left` is never set to true because you're if statement reads `if check_crossed_ref() and not check_crossed_ref()` where both instances of `check_crossed_ref()` are called with the exact same set of values `prev_x, prev_y, x, y, starting_x, starting_y, tolerance_x, tolerance_y`. In the future I'd recommend you add a bunch of print statements in your logic so you can see what the value of every statement is and what the values are at the end of the loop so you can see exactly what part of the logic is breaking down. Just adding something like this would let you know what parts of the lap test are breaking for example:

```py
print(crossed_left_to_right)
print(crossed_right_to_left)
print(returned_to_start)
```